# Continue as First Statement in Concise If Else

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, visual-studio-2015

I have the following if else statement inside of a `foreach` loop:

```
string date = GetDate(item)
if (date == null)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    article.Date = date;
}
```

And I would like to write this in the concise format using `? :`:

```
string date = GetDate(item)
date == null ? continue : article.Date = date;
```

From [what I gather](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx), this should work, as it is in the format `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`, where `first_expression` is `continue`, however in Visual Studio 2015 I am seeing these errors for the given areas:

**continue**

> Invalid expression term 'continue'
>
> Syntax error, ':' expected
>
> Invalid expression term 'continue'
>
> ; expected

**:**

> ; expected
>
> : expected

Is it possible to use `continue` in this types of `If/Else`? If not, is there any reason for this?

Comment: Is your code sitting in a white loop or foreach?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It doesn't really matter what type that `var` is, does it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't think that was relevant for this question as you don't need to know what value `date` holds to use `continue`.

Comment: I would say that using the ternary expression in your example is less readable anyway.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft inside ` foreach` (updated the question)

Comment: I'd prefer `foreach(var item in items.Where(x => x.Date != null)){ ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173144.aspx

> An expression is a sequence of one or more operands and zero or more operators that can be evaluated to a single value, object, method, or namespace

`continue` is not an expression

Your code is trying to assign `continue` to to your "date" variable. This doesn't make sense. I'm afraid there's no way to use the ternary operator for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

```
string date = GetDate(item)
date == null ? continue : article.Date = date;
```

Conditional ?: operator must return something, you can read it as:

```
           // if(smth) { return smth} else { return smthElse; }
var result = a ? b : c;
```

Obviously you cannot `return continue` because it is not a value.

What you can do is to assign the same value if returned result is null and check it using null coalescing operator. Assuming that there are no further operations in loop this code could be refactored to something like :

```
article.Date = GetDate(item) ?? article.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, With the `default` you can add default time `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` value to your variable `date` if the date is `null`,

```
date == null ? default(DateTime): article.Date = date;
```